# WIndows Phone Theme Settings

Tags: silverlight, themes, styles, windows-phone

I'm trying to get my app certified with the light theme for Windows Phone. I'm using a few custom ListBox styles, but I can't figure out why no pivot controls are visible. The foreground and background are both white, so they're invisible. I can't find any implicit or applied styles on the pivot control. TextBlocks have the same problem. From what I've read, the theme settings should be handled by the OS shouldn't they?

Comment: I don't understand why the resources aren't being applied. In my ResourceDictionary, I have a style:

<Color x:Key="PhoneForegroundColor">#000000</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}"/>

The on any PivotControl or TextBlock, if I use Foreground="#FF000000", the forground changes to black, wheras if I sue the resource with Fooreground={StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}", the foreground is white, and invisible. Why aren't the styles taking effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-define system resources since those are automatically added to the application at runtime, therefore rendering your ResourceDictionary redundant (and pretty much useless). Try applying the default system styles first. Also, post the XAML so that it is easier to help you fix it.

Comment: I had a reference to the dark themes hiding away inside my resource dictionary.